# Switching monad within a for comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to use a for-comprehension to process instances of `Option`s. However, as my last step, a function I use doesn't return an option but a `List[Option[Something]]` (Note, not an `OptionT[List, Something]`). I only want to proceed if all options in the list are instances of `Some`. Is there a clean way to process this as part of the flatMap calls? Currently I am set up like this:

```
for {
  o1     <- businessLogic1
  o2     <- businessLogic2(o1)
  rawList = businessLogic3(o2)
  list   <- if (rawList.forall(_.isDefined)) 
              Some(rawList.map(_.get)) 
            else 
              None
} { /* processing list */ }
```

I am sorry in case this question has been asked but I don't know the terminology of what I am looking for so I can't search the web effectively in this regard.

In case I am missing an essential theoretical point, please provide pointers to literature or other resources on the *thing* I seem to be having troubles understanding.

Comment: Example 3: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html? Could you just at the end add if and check the content of the list, just before yielding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can not mix Monads. Remember `for` is just sugar syntax for `flatMap` which has a signature like **(F[A], A => F[B]) => F[B]**
So you have to had the same Monad outside and inside.

Also, if you have a list of options and you want an option of list, you can use `sequence` *(from cats)*

```
def processList(rawList: List[Foo]): List[Bar] = ???

val result: Option[List[Bar]] = for {
  o1      <- businessLogic1
  o2      <- businessLogic2(o1)
  rawList <- businessLogic3(o2).sequence
} yield processList(rawList)
```

---

If you are not using **cats** and do not want to include it, you can create your own `sequence` **extension method** pretty easily just for a list of options.

```
implicit class ListOps[A](private val list: List[Option[A]]) extends AnyVal {
  def sequence: Option[List[A]] = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remaining: List[Option[A]], acc: List[A]): Option[List[A]] =
      remaining match {
        case Some(a) :: xs => loop(remaining = xs, a :: acc)
        case None :: _     => None
        case Nil           => Some(acc.reverse)
      }
    loop(remaining = list, acc = List.empty)
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a really cool solution, thank you! I will ask the team whether we can bring in the cats dependency.

Comment: @NiklasVest ah, I thought you were using **cats** because you mentioned `OptionT`. However a custom implementation of `sequence` just for **List** and **Option** is pretty easy. I will edit the answer with it in a while.

Comment: I am considering to start using it since I am pushing for more FP in our team anyway. Coincidentally I had already written down a pretty similar method for "inverting" the types, though not as gracefully as you have here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a cleaner way of doing the test:

```
for {
  o1 <- businessLogic1
  o2 <- businessLogic2(o1)
  rawList = businessLogic3(o2) if rawList.forall(_.isDefined)
  list = rawList.flatten
} {/* processing list */}
```

Alternatively you can create the flattened list first and then compare sizes:

```
for {
  o1 <- businessLogic1
  o2 <- businessLogic2(o1)
  rawList = businessLogic3(o2)
  list = rawList.flatten if list.size == rawList.size
} {/* processing list */}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `/* process list */` is done only for the side effects, i.e. no `yield`, and the ultimate goal is to process the individual elements of `list`, unwrapped from their `Some(x)` status, then you might do something like this.

```
for {
  o1 <- businessLogic1
  o2 <- businessLogic2(o1)
  lst = businessLogic3(o2)
  if lst.forall(_.nonEmpty)
  x <- lst.flatten
} {/* process x */}
```

Comment: Would you suggest something different if I used a yield statement instead of regular side effects?